# Training model on yolo but -nan and nan

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, yolo

I want to train model on yolo but after one step give nan and -nan
I have 300 images in different size(almost 600*600)
and one class to detect Image. before I gave good result with 100 images (%75 accuracy of detection)
but I want to give best result.

[image: train]

> tiny_yolo.cfg

```
[net]
batch=64
subdivisions=8
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
max_batches = 120000
policy=steps
steps=-1,100,80000,100000
scales=.1,10,.1,.1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=30
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=30
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=30
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=30
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=30
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=30
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=30
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

###########

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=30
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=30
activation=linear

[region]
anchors = 0.738768,0.874946,  2.42204,2.65704,  4.30971,7.04493,  10.246,4.59428,  12.6868,11.8741
bias_match=1
classes=1
coords=4
num=5
softmax=1
jitter=.2
rescore=1
small_object=1

object_scale=5
noobject_scale=1
class_scale=1
coord_scale=1

absolute=1
thresh = .6
random=1
```

and I split 80-20 train and test data 
I use this [darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/tree/master/build/darknet)

please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget config makefile in darknet.
I using Google Colab and first must be defined use GPU and CUDNN.

[image: Makefile(darknet)]